# Automatically setting the rendering frame range in compositing

Tags: rendering, scripting, compositing-nodes

Is there any way to set the frame rendering range based on the Movie Clip input node (using a script)?  I would like to automatically render different movie files, but in order to do that I need to correctly set the rendering range to cover the entire movies duration in number of frames. I tried looking for a parameter in Movie Clip node that would perhaps contain the clip duration, or frame count, but I wasn't able to find anything like that. Is there perhaps a different way this can be achieved?

My compositing workspace looks like this:
[image: workspace]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I just wasn't accessing the right object type. The movie clip node contains a **clip** parameter, which contains the data I needed. The frame end range can then be set like this:

```
frameCount = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].node_tree.nodes["MovieClip"].clip.frame_duration
bpy.context.scene.frame_end = frameCount
```

Full specification of the *MovieClip* datatype can be found [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.MovieClip.html?highlight=movieclip)